# How to use pipe in google colab

Tags: bash, pipe, google-colaboratory

I tried pipe in google colab using this code but it didn't work :

```
!bcftools mpileup -B -d 10000 -f ref-input.fa file-input.bam | !bcftools call -m -v -Ob -o output.bcf
```

Any suggestions, thanks in advance?

Comment: do you need ! on both commands ? (e.g. have you tried `!bcftools mpileup -B -d 10000 -f ref-input.fa file-input.bam | bcftools call -m -v -Ob -o output.bcf`) ?

Comment: I tried this too and didn't work :/

Comment: Interesting. Any useful error message you're getting ? Have you tried running one command at a time, checking the output at each step ? (I haven't used bcftools but I'm hoping there's a verbose option that will print detailed output to console which should help track down errors along the way). HTH

Comment: I actually tried the second command without ! again and it worked this time, maybe there were some problem with my notebook or something, thank you for your help.